# I'm in trouble with making a differentiating function in OCaml (not about syntax issue)

Tags: list, ocaml, differential-equations

```
  type aexp = 
  | Const of int
  | Var of string
  | Power of string * int
  | Times of aexp list
  | Sum of aexp list

  let rec diff : aexp * string -> aexp
  = fun (exp, var) -> 
    match exp with
    |Const a -> Const 0
    |Var x -> if x = var then Const 1 else Var x
    |Power (s, i) -> 
        if s = var then Times [Const i; Power (s, i - 1)] else Power (s, i)
    |Times l ->
        begin match l with
            |h::t -> Sum ((Times (diff (h, var) :: t)) @ (h :: Times (diff (Times t, var))))        
        end
    |Sum l ->
        begin match l with
            |h::t -> Sum (diff(h, var) :: diff(t, var))
        end
```

This code is expected to work as follows :

```
diff (Times[Const 2; Var "x"], "x")
```

then the output must be

```
Times[Const 2; Const 1]
```

because if we differentiate 2x, the result is 2

but the error occurs and it says :

```
File "", line 18, characters 20-25:
Error: This variant expression is expected to have type 'a list
       The constructor Times does not belong to type list
```

Why this error happens? I think there are some spots that are wrong, but I can't find any logical incorrectness.

Answer (score 2):

Some mathematical notes:

- The derivative of a variable not `x` by a variable `x` is zero, not the original variable.
- The same for a power of a variable not `x`, it is also a constant relative to `x`.
- Why only powers of variables, `(a+b)^i` is not possible. The more general case is as easy as the special case.

For the derivative of the product consider three factors and include that the first recursive step splits `u` and `v*w`

```
(u*v*w)' = u'*v*w + u*(v'*w+v*w')
```

In a prefix notation this can be written as

```
diff(*[u,v,w])=+[*[u',v,w],*[u,+[*[v',w],*[v,w']]]]
```

which should be reflected in something like

```
|h::t -> Sum ((Times (diff (h, var) :: t)) @ (Times (h :: (diff (Times t, var)))))
```

As two-element lists, could this also be written as

```
|h::t -> Sum ( Times (diff (h, var) :: t) , Times (h ,diff (Times t, var)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this expression:

```
h :: Times (diff (Times t, var))
```

for simplicity let's substitute `diff (Times t, var)`, with the `dtdv`, so that we have

```
h :: Times dtdv
```

The `::` infix constructor requires that an expression to the left of its should have type `'a`, while an expression to the right should have a value of type `'a list`. An expression to the right is `Times dtdv`, and constructor `Times` creates values of type `aexp`, not values of type list.

Btw, you also have two more errors and two more warnings. These errors are of the same kind, i.e., you're trying to apply a value of type `aexp` in a place where a list is required, i.e., here:

```
 Times (diff (h, var) :: t)) @ (h :: Times (diff (Times t, var))
```

Let's simplify it again

```
 Times (dhv::t) @ rest
```

The `@` operator expects lists on both sides, and `Times something`, as we already discussed, are not a list.

It looks like, that it is hard for you to pass through the big amount of parenthesis and precedence rules. I hate parenthesis. So, I always try to use `let ... in` sparingly, e.g., let's rewrite the following expression:

```
Sum ((Times (diff (h, var) :: t)) @ (h :: Times (diff (Times t, var))))
```

With a more verbose, but understanble version:

```
let h' = diff (h,var) in
let t' = diff (Times t,var) in
let lhs = Times (h'::t) in
let rhs = h :: Times t' in
Sum (lhs@rhs)
```

Now it is much more readable, and you can tackle with all problems one by one.

Also, I'm would suggest not to try to solve everything in a big fat function, but instead separate things into smaller functions that are easier to handle, this will also solve you a problem with the match inside a match, e.g., the following function has a structure that is much easier to understand:

```
let rec diff : aexp * string -> aexp = fun (exp, var) ->
    match exp with
    |Const a -> Const 0
    |Var x -> if x = var then Const 1 else Var x
    |Power (s, i) -> diff_power s i
    |Times l -> diff_times l
    |Sum l -> diff_sum l
and diff_power s i =
  if s = var then Times [Const i; Power (s, i - 1)] else Power (s, i)
and diff_times l = match l with
  |h::t -> Sum ((Times (diff (h, var) :: t)) @ (h :: Times (diff (Times t, var))))
and diff_sum l = match l with
  |h::t -> Sum (diff(h, var) :: diff(t, var))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me.
I still wonder that I have already declared that Times -> aexp list
and I thought that means the Times constructor makes list of type aexp.
How can I fix this..?

Comment: @송재민: `diff (Times t, var)` returns or should return a sum of products. Which is an `aexp` structure `Sum` with the list of addens inside. It seems non-sensical to apply the `Times` constructor to the `Sum` structure. The correct result should be something like `diff(Times[u,v,w],x)=Sum[Times[u',v,w], Times[u,Sum[Times[v',w], Times[v,Sum[Times[w']]]]]]`. Ideally, single-element sums and products are unpacked...